# How to update Label value in Gridview coulmn one by one after completing first count of loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can i show gridview cell value one by one after ping the single ip address and then ping the other ip and show its status in gridview cell and then go to third and so on.

here is my code.

```
            count = dgvStatus.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string Name = dgvStatus.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
                string IP = dgvStatus.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                try
                {
                    Ping ping = new Ping();
                    PingReply reply = ping.Send(IP, 5000);

                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        result = "UP";
                        Label status = (Label)dgvStatus.Rows[i].FindControl("lblstatus");
                        status.Text = result;
                        Panel panel = (Panel)dgvStatus.Rows[i].FindControl("Panel1");
                        panel.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "DOWN";
                        Label status = (Label)dgvStatus.Rows[i].FindControl("lblstatus");
                        status.Text = result;
                        Panel panel = (Panel)dgvStatus.Rows[i].FindControl("Panel1");
                        panel.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
                catch (PingException)
                {
                    result = "UNREACHABLE";
                    Label status = (Label)dgvStatus.Rows[i].FindControl("lblstatus");
                    status.Text = result;
                    Panel panel = (Panel)dgvStatus.Rows[i].FindControl("Panel1");
                    panel.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }`
```

Comment: What is the problem?Is it not working?

Comment: Create a method to update the GridViews cell value based on the ping result?  We need further information on what you are trying to achieve and how it is not functioning as expected.

Comment: gridview cells are updating but after loop completion. i want that after the first count or first loop completed gridview row cell show the result and on the second count of loop it will show the result in second row's cell of gridview and so on.....

Comment: and before the loop count it shoes "Waiting..." in gridview cells